# Watir Random Popup

Tags: javascript, html, ruby, cucumber, watir-webdriver

High all, I'm testing this e-commerce and I get this random popup (it's a div)that gets in the way of my scripts, given its random appereance I can't relly predict when it's going to show, otherwise I can easily interact with it, as it is a simple div, whenever I see it. It's there a way that can I catch this popup and do as I please whenever it dares to show? Thanks in advance

```
<div class="fsrFloatingMid"><div class="fsrInvite">
<div class="fsrDialogs">
    <div style="margin-left: 0px;" class="fsrDialog ">
        <div class="fsrLogos">
            <img src="/_ui/desktop/common/foresee/sitelogo.gif" alt="" class="fsrSiteLogo">
            <img src="/_ui/desktop/common/foresee/fsrlogo.gif" alt="Foresee" class="fsrCorpLogo">
        </div>
        <h1 class="fsrHeading">We'd welcome your feedback!</h1>
        <p class="fsrBlurb">Some bullshit text</p>
        <p class="fsrSubBlurb">The survey is designed to measure your entire experience, please look for it at the <u>conclusion</u> of your visit.</p>
        <p class="fsrAttribution">This survey is conducted by an independent company, on behalf of the site you are visiting.</p>
        <div style="" class="fsrB">
            <div class="fsrAcceptButtonContainer">
                <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="fsrAcceptButton" tabindex="2">Yes, I'll give feedback</a><span class="hidden-accessible">&nbsp;(this will launch a new window)</span>
            </div>

            <div class="fsrDeclineButtonContainer"><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="fsrDeclineButton"    tabindex="1">No, thanks</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="fsrFooter">
            <a href="http://some-bullshit-url" tabindex="5" title="Validate TRUSTe privacy certification" target="_blank" class="fsrTE"><img src="/_ui/desktop/common/foresee/truste.png" alt="TRUSTe verified" class="fsrTruste"></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<a href="#" role="button" tabindex="6" class="fsrCloseBtn">×<span class="hidden-accessible">Click to close.</span></a>
```

Comment: Is it a popup from your application on it is from the browser(e.g. a security alert)? if it is your application, then your developers might be able to tell what triggers the pop up randomly and if it is indeed a valid pop up. You can probably have a `rescue` and handle the pop up whenever it appears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this pop-up appears randomly then I think using the "protection proxy" design pattern would help most. The purpose of it is to execute a particular piece of code, in our example this:

```
if browser.div(class: 'fsrDialogs').exists?
      browser.a(class: 'fsrCloseBtn').click
end
```

BEFORE any method on the "subject" ("subject" is the object we wrap inside the Proxy class, in our case it's the browser) is called. The Proxy design pattern is pretty straightforward to implement in Ruby, here's how we'd do it in your particular case:

```
class WatirProxy
  attr_reader :subject
  def initialize(browser)
    @subject = browser
  end

  def method_missing(method, *args)
    puts "I am executing the code below before calling #{method} with args #{args}"
    if subject.div(class: 'fsrDialogs').exists?
      subject.a(class: 'fsrCloseBtn').click
    end

    subject.send(method, *args)
  end
end
```

You can remove the puts below `method_missing` in production, however, I'd recommend you keep it for now if you're not 100% clear on how the code below works.

Let's try playing with it:

```
browser = WatirProxy.new(Watir::Browser.new(:chrome)) # you can use ANY method on browser, although it's wrapped in a proxy
browser.goto 'https://google.com'
puts browser.text_field(name: 'q').exists?
```

Ruby should output:

```
I am executing the code below before calling goto with args ["https://google.com"]
I am executing the code below before calling text_field with args [{:name=>"q"}]
true # May change if google search box 'name' attribute changed to something other than 'q' in the future
```

In your specific case, this pop-up is raising errors because the browser didn't expect it, now we make sure there's a check BEFORE ANY method on browser is called. A great book for reading about the Proxy design pattern (and some other useful ones in Ruby) is [Design Patterns in Ruby](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321490452) by Russ Olsen.

Comment: Thank you for your response I was looking for something a bit more DRY though, but thanks anyway

Comment: Put this code in a proc and then do browser.add_checker(&proc_name) if you want one-liner. Did you find all of this info useful? If yes, please accept this answer, thanks.

Comment: I'm afraid It didn't do it as the pop up does not show when a page is loaded, it's totally random, I appreaciate your answer though I'm afraid I can't accept the answer because it doesn't quite solve my problem, although is very useful when you know when a pop us is going to show, thanks again

Comment: If this thing is TOTALLY random, then we must go the opposite way. This thing is stopping you from executing browser methods and must be checked on BEFORE any method is executed. See my updated answer on how to accomplish this.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help mate I took the answer as valid :) for your efforts in helping me

Comment: Appreciate the thanks, feel free to upvote this answer as well so other can see it as more valid. Best regards and good luck with your efforts

Answer (score 0):

`@browser.link(class: "fsrCloseBtn").click if @browser.h1(class: "hsrHeading").visible?`

Something like this should be enough. Obviously, sub whatever you name your WebDriver instance for `@browser`. This clicks the close link if the dialog is visible and skips this step if the dialog is not there. My syntax might be a little wrong, so double check that. I'm used to wrapping all this in page-object, which would look like:

`page_class.close_dialog if page_class.dialog_header_element.visible?`

Answer (score 0):

Had same issue with Foresee survey, I got around it by adding

```
 while browser.text.include?("We'd welcome your feedback!") == false do
   browser.refresh
   sleep 1
  end
 browser.link(:class => /declineButton/).click
end
```

to the first step after going to the page. It's not the best option but it deals with the Foresee because once you close the window you get a fsr cookie that prevents the survey from popping up again during that browser session. The "sleep 1" was added so chrome would slow down and look for the Foresee survey. Hope it helps.